# How to filter column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `purchase` table:

```
id     | Date       | Material_name  | Parts   
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 06/10/2015 | Tyre           |  887745;99836
-------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 07/10/2015 | Tyre           |  12564;098745;009845
```

This table contains 5 Different type of Tyre in Two Single Purchase

**Used Parts**  Table

```
id     | Date      |  Material_name  | Used_Parts
----------------------------------------------------------
1      |08/10/2015  |   Tyre         |  12564 
----------------------------------------------------------
2      |08/10/2015  |   Tyre         |  99836
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**unused Parts**

```
1)887745
2)098745
3)009845
```

How can I fetch unused Parts using a MySQL query. I don't what know to try. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Maintain separate table for `Parts`. And in purchase table refer those parts by a foreign key (e.g. Parts.ID). Otherwise doing this job in MYSQL alone would be cumbersome.

Comment: For the current table structures can't you do the job in application level?

Comment: Please can you help me to structure table ....

Comment: Please have a look at this [file](http://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/02/07/purchaseparts-table-design/)